# How do I display the following data in a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have been trying to do the following exercise, which is to create a query using SQL, "Find number of salesmen who have more than 3 clients in a week. Display the staff ID, staff name, client ID, client name and number of clients who the salesman met with."

The entities and relevant fields are:

```
Staff:   [Staff_ID (PK), Staff_Name, ...]
Clients: [Client_ID (PK), Client_Name, Staff_ID (FK), ...]
Sales:   [Sale_ID (PK), Client_ID (FK), Staff_ID (FK), Date_of_Sale, ...]
(All data are strings except Date_of_Sale, which is in DATE format)
```

I've tried to accomplish this, with the following:

```
SELECT t.Staff_ID, t.Staff_Name, COUNT(s.Client_ID), 
COUNT(c.Client_Name), DATEPART(wk, s.Date_of_Sale) as Week
FROM Clients c, Staff t, Sales s
GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, s.Date_of_Sale), t.Staff_ID, t.Staff_Name
HAVING COUNT(DATEPART(wk, s.Date_of_Sale)) > 3
```

I know it's incorrect, but I don't know how to fix it, as I am very unskilled in sql. I want to understand how to do this and I could (to a limited extent) by reverse engineering it. Even better, if someone were to explain it for me, I would much appreciate it, thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by week? is it monday to sunday ? sample data with desired output  with help

Comment: @saravanatn Yes, I believe so, or even if the week begins on monday or so its fine as long as it counts in weeks. DATEPART(wk, s.Date_of_Sale) should find which week of the year the date is, and if that could be grouped together based on client_id and then sorted by staff_id, it should work

Comment: Its easy .Can you kindly share create and insert statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a big difference between *number of clients who the salesman met with* and *the number of sales the salesman made*. Mainly, whether or not to count repeat visits to the same client. The former says no, the latter says yes, because the number of clients hasn't changed but the number of sales has.

```
-- Get list of clients with sales greater than 3 in a week
WITH SalesCount AS (
    SELECT Client_ID AS 'Client', DATEPART(wk, Date_of_Sale) AS 'week', 
        COUNT(Staff_ID) AS 'Sales_Count'
    FROM Sales
    GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, Date_of_Sale), Client_ID
    HAVING COUNT(Staff_ID) > 3  ),
-- Shorten the list to unique entries and add the StaffID
ClientList AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT sc.Client, c.Staff_ID
    FROM SalesCount AS sc
    INNER JOIN Clients AS c ON sc.Client = c.Client_ID) ,
-- Create a count of clients visited
ClientCount AS (
    SELECT COUNT(l.Client) AS visitors, l.Staff_ID
    FROM ClientList AS l
    GROUP BY l.Staff_ID)

SELECT cc.visitors, cc.Staff_ID, l.Client, t.Staff_Name
FROM ClientCount AS cc
INNER JOIN ClientList AS l ON cc.Staff_ID = l.Staff_ID
INNER JOIN Staff AS t ON t.Staff_ID = l.Staff_ID 
INNER JOIN Clients AS c ON l.Client = c.Client_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we go

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *, DATEPART(wk, s.Date_of_Sale) as SALES_WEEK
    FROM Clients c
    INNER JOIN Sales s ON c.Client_ID = s.CLIENT_ID
    INNER JOIN Staff t ON t.STAFF_ID = s.STAFF_ID
)

SELECT SALES_WEEK, Staff_ID, Staff_Name, COUNT(1) AS NO_OF_SALES
FROM CTE
GROUP BY SALES_WEEK, Staff_ID, Staff_Name
HAVING COUNT(1) > 3
```

Hope this works as expected

Comment: It says the column 'Staff_ID' was specified multiple times for 'CTE'?

Comment: I did put SELECT * there, which will select all columns from all tables, including STAFF_ID which exists on 2 or more tables, there will be duplication, you going to need to customize and specify what are the columns to be selected, like SELECT t.STAFF_ID, t.STAFF_NAME, etc depending on what columns you want to display

Comment: SELECT * isn't a best practice sometimes, it's better to be more specific which columns to display